# Props are not passed down to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why my prop values are not being applied to my component. Specifically the row, column and pix value

Board Component:

```
import '../App.css'

export default function Board({ row, column, pix, children }) {
  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'grid',
      gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${{ column }}, ${{ pix }}px)`,
      gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${{ row }}, ${{ pix }}px)`,
    }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Game Component:

```
import Cell from './Components/Cell'
import Board from './Components/Board'
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

export default function Game({ row, column, pix }) {
const boardDimensions = {
width: 50,
height: 50
}

const array2D = Array(boardDimensions.height).fill().map((row) =\> Array(boardDimensions.width).fill(0))
const \[fiboCells, setFiboCells\] = useState(array2D)

return (
\<div className="center"\>
\<Board row={row} column={column} pix={pix}\>
{
fiboCells.map((row, i) =\> row.map((col, j) =\> (
\<Cell
value={col}
rowIndex={i}
colIndex={j}
colour="red"
/\>
)))
}
\</Board\>
\</div\>
)
}
```

App Component:

```
import './App.css';
import Game from './Game'

function App() {
  return (
    <Game row={50} column={50} pix={25}/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I expected a grid of 50 x 50 bit instead its all in one vertical line

Comment: Can you update this to a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) as a [mcve], and indicate specifically what problem you are observing?

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how to do that

Comment: Well, for starters the code shown is filled with syntax errors.  Can you correct those?  Additionally, in the question's edit history you corrected a typo.  Did you re-test your code after correcting that?  Aside from that, what specific observation are you making which indicates that there is a problem?  What debugging have you done?  If you can provide an example which *shows* the problem and describe what actual problem you're observing, the community would be more easily able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is wrong:

```
`repeat(${{ column }}, ${{ pix }}px)`
```

It's effectively passing *objects* into the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), not *values*.  Observe the resulting string:

```js
const column = 10;
const pix = 20;
console.log(`repeat(${{ column }}, ${{ pix }}px)`);
```

Which of course is not valid CSS.

Don't wrap the values in curly braces, just pass them directly to the template literal:

```
`repeat(${column}, ${pix}px)`
```

---

As an aside... This is why *debugging* and *observing* is important.  You have *assumed* that "props are not passed to the component".  This observation is easily proven false by simply logging the prop values to the console within the component, allowing you to observe that they *are* being passed to the component.  Which means the problem was something else.

Don't assume.  Debug and observe.  That's how you identify and correct problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert them into states instead of pros.
Changes in props, do not impact the component, since props are read-only.

or
you can create some state variables and pass them as input to "Board" component.

let me know, if this helps you or not.

Comment: Hi Ankit. First of all thanks for commenting. Second, are you saying I have to apply state in my components? Is it not possible for values to be passed down?